# Bayesian variable selection in R

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, model-selection

There are at least three R packages providing some functions to perform a Bayesian selection variable in linear Gaussian regression model: LearnBayes, mombf and BMA.

I would be glad to know some opinions about which one is the best.

Comment: There is also spikeSlabGAM that has many interesting options and properties: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spikeSlabGAM/index.html